# Executing a function repeatedly after set seconds of program initiation

Tags: python, time

The following program wishes to execute `c()` after every 5 seconds of the program initiation, `a()` after every 10 seconds of program initiation and `b()` after every 20 seconds of program initiation.
Thus, after 10 seconds of the program being executed, I want the following output:

#After 5 seconds
**5 seconds have passed since execution**
#After 10 seconds
**5 seconds have passed since execution**
**10 seconds have passed since execution**
This would repeat in the following manner.
The problem I have faced is that time.sleep() offsets the rest of the program, causing a delay, and the message isn't printed in exactly 10 seconds, but after an offest of additional 5 seconds. Is there any method to combat this?

```py
import time
def a():
    print("10 seconds have passed since execution")
def b(): 
    print("20 seconds have passed since execution")
def c():
    print("5 seconds have passed since execution")

def runA():
    time.sleep(10)
    a()

def runB():
    time.sleep(20)
    b()

def runC():
    time.sleep(5)
    c()

while True:
    runA()
    runB()
    runC()
```

Comment: Use multi-threading.

Comment: what is that? i have never heard of this term

Comment: You need to use concurrency

Comment: I agree with Barmar, multithreading can take care of this but it is quite advanced. Perhaps you can take the difference? So if you want a total of 20 seconds, you can use time.sleep(5) (print 5 seconds have passed), time.sleep(5), now 10 seconds have passed and time.sleep(10) now a total of 20 seconds have passed. I think you have a misconception of how time.sleep() works.

Comment: Again, i do not want to change the .sleep values, as my program requires such an action to be  executed many times throughout the day, and if i used the difference, it would be quiet complicated

Comment: You should google it to learn, this is not a tutoring service.

Comment: okay, sure i will see what multithreading is.

Comment: @CeliusStingher , i know that using time.sleep() will cause the program to sleep, i wanted to know if there was a way around this, or if i could use another function in the time module

Comment: a way around is using `threading`/`multiprocessing`/`concurrency`

Comment: if you would run it in diferent order and use different values in `sleep()` then you could get text in expected moment. OR put items on list and use loop which every 1 minut check if it is time to display any element from list. But this will not work if you want to use something else in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `threading`/`multiprocessing`/`concurrency` to run functions at the same time.

Minimal example with `threading`.

In `target=` you have to use function's name without `()` and later  `thread` will use `()` to start this function.

```
import time
import threading

def a():
    print("10 seconds have passed since execution")
    
def b(): 
    print("20 seconds have passed since execution")
    
def c():
    print("5 seconds have passed since execution")

def runA():
    time.sleep(10)
    a()

def runB():
    time.sleep(20)
    b()

def runC():
    time.sleep(5)
    c()

while True:
    print('start')
    
    # create threads    
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runA) # function's name without ()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=runB) # function's name without ()
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=runC) # function's name without ()

    # start code in threads    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    
    # wait for ends
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```